# Add multiple limits for multiple Textfields

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm searching to limit the number of characters that an user can enter in a textfield.

I find this method and it's working very well

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let currentCharacterCount = textField.text?.characters.count ?? 0
    if (range.length + range.location > currentCharacterCount){
        return false
    }
    let newLength = currentCharacterCount + string.characters.count - range.length
    return newLength <= 25
```

But now, I wanted to put different limits for 2 different textfields.

Does someone have a clue?

Comment: Use the `textField` parameter to distinguish between different textviews if you want to use the same delegate for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting `textField == yourTextField`

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
if textField == textField1 {

let currentCharacterCount = textField.text?.characters.count ?? 0
if (range.length + range.location > currentCharacterCount){
    return false
}
let newLength = currentCharacterCount + string.characters.count - range.length
return newLength <= 25
} 

else if textField == textField2 {
  // set for textField2
}

return false
```

Comment: Thank you  ! I just had a "return false" at the end of the method, because I got some error ("Missing return in a function expected to return 'BOOL'") I don't realy know if it's OK but it's working perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign tag property for every text field and later you can use it.

Assigning tag property:

```
firstTextField.tag = 2015
secondTextField.tag = 2016
thirdTextField.tag = 2017
```

Later, you can use it like this:

```
*//you can also use if else cases here*
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    switch textField.tag {
        case 2015:// set your rules here for firstTextField

        case 2016:// set your rules here for secondTextField

        case 2017:// set your rules here for thirdTextField

        default:print(" definitely it works")
    }
}
```